# How to copy user_nicename value into user_login

Tags: users, sql

a hacker put value "admin" into all user_login fields. i need to copy `user_nicename` value into the `user_login` so users can login. is there a SQL command i can run to do this task in bulk, as their 1000s of users and doing manually would a hassle. kindly help if you can. thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following SQL query in PHPMyAdmin or similar.

```
UPDATE wp_users SET user_login = user_nicename;
```

`wp_users` is the table for users (make sure it matches yours)